# Getting deviceId with GatewayId in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there any way to get a device Id which gateway(vyatta) is running?
I have the gateway Id and this is the code I've tried, but it returns all hardwares in account.

```
    private void getDeviceIdWithGwId(){

        Gateway.Service gservice = Gateway.service(client, 18612llll);
        gservice.withMask().account().hardware();
        Gateway gw = gservice.getObject();

        Account account = gw.getAccount();

        List<Hardware> hdList = account.getHardware();

        System.out.println("size of hardware : " + hdList.size());
        for(Hardware hardware:hdList){
            System.out.println("hardware ID : " + hardware.getId());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to list all vyatta servers in your account :

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways

but you need to make sure you have enough permissions to list the vyatta servers.

In order to get the hardwareIds you can use a mask like this:

```
objectMask=mask[members[hardware]]
```

see this example using REST to list all the svyatta servers and its hardware:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways?objectMask=mask[members[hardware]]
```

this example will list all the hardwareids of given a vyatta server:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/$GatwayID/getObject?objectMask=mask[members[hardware]]
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks.. I found its hardware Id in a member array. Can you explain about members? What case a member can be added in a gateway? If a gateway has HA configuration, the num of member will be added?

Comment: well the members basically are the nodes(servers)  of your vyatta server, if you have a HA configuration you will have two members, if you have a single configuration you only will have one member. the max number of members that you can have is 2.